# Why image base of spring boot microservices changed from alpine to ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, jhipster, alpine-linux

Why image base in containers of spring boot microservices changed from alpine to ubuntu

- In Jhipster 5.3.4: openjdk:8-jre-alpine
- In Jhipster 6.10.1: ubuntu...

It seems, the image ubuntu have more MB of older image base...

Thanks

Comment: OpenJDK >8 doesn't support Alpine as a base distribution.